# How to use Hugin straight line control points?

Tags: panorama, hugin

I'm in the process of stitching a very badly shot panorama so I'm placing control points and lines by hand in Hugin.

In the documentation I found out that you can indicate straight features, using [straight line control points](http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Control_Points_tab#Straight_line_control_points) (SLCP for the sake of brevity).
However, it is not clear to me how to do this when one straight line appears in multiple photos.

If `i1` and `i2` share the same straight feature I would simply add a SLCP with the name `line3`.
However, when I `i1`, `i2` and `i3` all share the same straight feature I have two options:

1. Add SLCP named `line3` between `i1` and `i2`, between `i2` and `i3` and between `i1` and `i3`.
2. Add SLCP named `line3` between `i1` and `i2`, between `i2` and `i3` but name it `line4` and between `i1` and `i3` and name it `line5`.

So does the naming of the line matter to Hugin? If I would go with option 1 would Hugin understand that it's the same straight feature I'm trying to align?
Or should every SLCP be only used for one image pair (option 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight line features apply to a single image. You set your view to have the same image on the left and right and set the two end points. If you have three images, you'll do this once for each image.

Comment: So I can not tell Hugin that there's a single line that appears in all images that should be matched?

Comment: I don't think so. Not sure that it would provide any advantage.

Comment: @Wayne, not sure that's the case. To quote from the Hugin website: "Straight line control points were added later and have a similar effect as horizontal and vertical points, except that the straight line can be at any angle. ... Although two points are sufficient to define a horizontal or vertical line, more are required for these lines at arbitrary angles. Since the script file format only supports 'pairs' of points, a straight line is generally defined with four, six or eight etc... control points."

Comment: @inkista: I'll admit I've only used horizontal and vertical, not "straight", and I can't imagine how the quote works out in terms of mouse clicks and menu choices. In any case, it looks like multiple points are used because of the arbitrary angle, not because it spans images.

Comment: @Wayne Similar experience, but horizontal and vertical points can also span images. No reason straight line can't, either.

Comment: @inksta: How can horizontal lines, say, span images. As far as I can tell, you have to place the two endpoints in the same image. How would you do this in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the naming matters.

In my experience:
a) Define the lines as well as you can in each photo separately. This will help the system understand any distortions involved.
b) Define matching points between your photos along the lines.

In general, to the extent you do both of these things well, you'll get a good result.